# Windows PHP exec / shell_exec with phantomjs always returns null

Tags: php, windows, exec, phantomjs

I'm running PHP 5.4.9 on Windows server

I've tried running all script commands in PHP (exec, shell_exec, system, proc_open, passthru). All seem to return empty or null.

I've added phantomjs as a PATH variable.

And running `phantomjs --version` in command prompt, and it returns `1.8.2`

Although when I try to run

```
$return = exec("phantomjs --version")
```

or

```
$return = shell_exec("phantomjs --version", $output)
```

`$return` is always null and `$output` is empty.

I made sure IUSR and IIS_IUSRS users have permission to run phantomjs.exe

Safe mode is disabled in php.ini

Also, I tried running `exec('ls') && exec('ipconfig /all')`, and those output the data I'm expecting.

I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: are you sure phantomjs is in the path of the shell being exec()'d by the server? just because it's in YOUR account's path, it may not be in the IUSR_IIS account's path.

Comment: Try the following and see if either $out or $ret are populated.  $out will be an array.  exec('phantomjs --version'.' 2>&1',$out,$ret);

Comment: The path is in the System Variables -> Path variable.

Comment: when using Gavin's recommendation, $out returns an empty array, and $ret is 1.

exec('phantomjs --version'.'2>&1',$out,$ret);

out: 
array(0) { } 
ret: 
int(1)

Comment: Not especially helpful,  but I can tell you that 1 is an error code (should be 0)  and $out should have caught any output to standard out,  so looks like there was none. If you have control over the server try setting the php process to run under a system account (for testing only)  to  clear the doubt of permissions issues.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem..
The thing is phantomjs requires complete path for all
Here is the solution I came up with:

```
$getout = exec('D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\phantomjsdir\\phantomjs.exe D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\rasterisejsdir\\rasterize.js http://localhost/pagetobecaptured/test D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\outputfiledir\\test2.jpg "1800px*840px"',$o,$e);
```

Comment: Well, I put the path to the phantomjs.exe to my PATH system variable. It was instantly accessible using CLI. But it did NOT work in my Apache running under Local System account without using the complete path to the executable (just as you write).

So I thought the Apache service might need to get updated with the new PATH somehow - either by restarting the PC or by restarting the service itself. The latter worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close to a solution. It's basically:

```
$stdout = shell_exec('time /T');
echo $stdout;
```

You need to make sure, that the Phantom binary is either on path or called with full-path.

For a full example executing PhantomJS, see the [driver file of "jakoch/PHPUnit-headless"](https://github.com/jakoch/phpunit-headless/blob/master/src/PHPUnit/Extensions/Phantom/Driver.php#L161).